# Proving the existence of an invertible square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $A$ is a square matrix with real values. Show that there exist an invertible square matrix $B$ such that matrix $B^{-1}AB$ is block upper triangular with diagonal blocks either of size $1\times1$ or of size $2 \times 2$ of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    a & -b \\
    b & a \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Solution: Let ${e_1,e_2,...,e_n}$ be a basis of $A$. $T:T(x)=Ax$

Let $ A = M[T,{e_1,...,e_n}]$

$ M[T,\{e_1,...,e_n\}] = M[I,\{b_1,...,b_n\},\{v_1,...,v_n\}] M[T,\{e_1,...,e_n\}]M[I,\{v_1,...,v_n\},\{b_1,...,b_n\}]$

Where $ B^{-1} = M[I,\{b_1,...,b_n\},\{v_1,...,v_n\}]$ and $B$ = $M[I,\{v_1,...,v_n\},\{b_1,...,b_n\}]$.

How do i show the resulting matrix of $B^{-1}AB$ is block upper triangular with diagonal blocks?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: No, you haven't at all specified what $v_i$ and $b_i$ are; what does "a basis of $A$" mean? (eigenvectors of $A$ will be useful, so will bases of $\mathbb R^n$, but you really have to tread carefully here); finally, the equation you write just looks like a change of basis equation. Why should the result have the given block upper triangular form?

Comment: This theorem is about a general classification (via similarity) of all matrices in terms of their eigenvalues. For different kinds of eigenvals, you get different corresponding blocks. For real eigenvals, with equal algebraic and geometric multiplicities, you will get $1\times 1$ blocks, and nothing above the main diagonal (the standard 'diagonalization' of matrices). For deficient eigenvals, you will have $1$'s above the diagonal (see 'Jordan form'/'Jordan blocks'). For complex eigenvals, they will appear in conjugate pairs, and they correspond to $2\times 2$ blocks in your problem statement.

Comment: $b_i$ and $v_i$ are bases of $B$  and suppose $e_i$ are orthonormal bases of $A$. Yes, the equation gives me a diagonal matrix. I don't know how to show the matrix is block upper triangular with diagonal blocks.Thanks for your hints though!

Comment: By "bases of $B$" I think you mean "eigenvectors of $B$ that form a basis of $\mathbb R^n$". You have two problems here: your $b_i$ are defined in terms of $B$, but your $B$ is defined in terms of $b_i$ (when you finish "Where $B^{-1} = \dots$"). AND: a general square matrix $A$ may very well **not** have a set of eigenvectors forming an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$. In particular, if $A$ has deficient eigenvalues (repeated, degenerate roots), or if $A$ has complex eigenvalues, the situation is not so simple.

Comment: Thanks! but I am still lost. Could you explain more about why my $B$ is problematic? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Can we use the fact that there exists a complex $B$ such that $B^{-1}AB$ is an upper triangular complex matrix?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So if I could use the fact, then my equation prove the statement? Thanks!

Comment: You're defining $B$ in terms of itself, rather than actually constructing a $B$ that does the needed job. See if your method works for a concrete $A$ (take $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$). You should be able to explicitly construct $B$ and tell me what the entries are. (the proof of this theorem is the generalization of the method you use for a concrete case; if you can't do this concrete case, then go back to your reading material and review all the above ideas first).

Comment: You're basically on the right track though. If $A$ were diagonalizable, the proof would go like this: let $v_i$ be a set of eigenvectors that form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$ (they might not be orthogonal, but that's ok). Let $B$ be a matrix whose columns are the $v_i$'s. Then $B$ is invertible (because the columns are linearly independent) and you can check $B^{-1}AB$ is diagonal (so it's a special subset of block upper triangular).

Comment: Can i suppose that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, then $A$ has a diagonal matrix with respect to some basis of $\mathbb R^2$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess i need to manipulate that give fact: $A$ is a square matrix of real values.

Comment: No, you cannot suppose that. As you say, $A$ is a square matrix with real entries, so you need to be able to handle the case that $A$ is not diagonalizable, has repeated roots, has complex roots, etc. If you don't know about Jordan blocks, Jordan form, etc. then you should be reading about that before you attempt this problem.

Comment: I will read it, and thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: For a proof of a slightly stronger statement, see [here](http://kurser.lobner.dk/LinAlg/Tilf%C2%B0jelser%20til%20Leons%20bog/RealSchur.pdf)